# Do you know of any Rails "Announcements" plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've noticed in various web apps that users are prompted with initial announcements to help them use the app for the first time (and users have the option to click "Don't show this message again in the future" or something similar)

Is there a plugin that does that? Or, would you simply program a many-to-many relationship between users and announcements, and maybe have a "disable" boolean column in there, to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need a many-to-many for that -- just add a `hide_announcement` column in your users table and set it to 0 anytime you update the announcement.

Comment: What if I have multiple announcements for various sections all across the app? Maybe create a column for all sections (something like hide_page1_announcement, hide_page2_announcement, etc)?

Comment: Then you should probably go the many to many association route.  Be careful though -- imagine the case where someone doesn't login for a long time -- they'll have to clear tons of announcements!  That's why the single announcement in the user column works great -- it gets reset so they only see the latest announcement.

Comment: Thank you bensie! Great recommendations. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about any plugins for it but you may want to take a look at Ryan Bates screencast about system wide announcements

http://railscasts.com/episodes/103-site-wide-announcements

Answer (score 4):

This is an old topic, but in case anyone comes across it looking for a gem with this functionality, Thoughtbot publishes the [paul_revere](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paul_revere) gem that provides simple functionality like this.

Answer (score 1):

[Rack::Downtime](https://github.com/sshaw/rack-downtime) can be used for downtime notifications, no database required. You can use an HTTP header, text file, environment variable and I think a few others. An ActiveRecord model could be used via a custom handler.